# Twig. Overriding already set variable

Tags: variables, overriding, twig

I've looked for resolving issue, that was asked in this question. https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/1244

But for me, somehow that does not work...

```
#layout.html.twig
{{ show }}

#base1.html.twig
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
{% set show = 0 %}

#base2.html.twig
{% extends 'base1.html.twig' %}
{% set show = 1 %}
```

But when i render base2, i see only 0 ... 
Why it is not 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works perfectly for me. I guess it’s a block problem. Maybe your base1's block appears after the base2's one and overrides the value.

The problem would appear with this code for example:

```
#base2.html.twig
{% extends 'base1.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    {% set show = 1 %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ show }}
{% endblock %}
```

You should try this:

```
#layout.html.twig
{% block content %}
    {% set show = 0 %}
    {{ show }}
{% endblock %}

#base1.html.twig
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% set show = 1 %}
    {{ show }}
{% endblock %}

#base2.html.twig
{% extends 'base1.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% set show = 2 %}
    {{ show }}
{% endblock %}
```

Displaying `show` variable at each step of the inheritance process, should help you to see what’s going wrong. The final response should display `0 1 2`.

Comment: wouldnt calling `parent()` output `0`?
wouldnt results be `0`, `0 1`, `0 2`?

Comment: @gondo, yep, calling `parent()` outputs the previous variable. So as I said, the final response will be `0 1 2`. `0` for the layout, `0 1` for the base1 and `0 1 2` for the base2.

Comment: i see, thanks for clarification, i thought that your 'final response' is per each block